# How to kill multiple processes?

Tags: vb.net, process, task

I found this code to kill a process.. But this this is only for 1 process`(MS Word)`.. What I want is to kill 2 or more process.

```
  For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "WINWORD", True) = 0 Then
            p.Kill()
        End If
    Next
```

I try to add `If String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "WINWORD","EXCEL", True) = 0 Then` but this code is error

I also try this `If String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "WINWORD , EXCEL", True) = 0 Then` and this code is ok but its not reading the Winword or excel

Comment: [`String.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "WINWORD", True) = 0 Or String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "EXCEL", True) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add more comparison like:

```
if String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "WINWORD", True) = 0 Or String.Compare(p.ProcessName, "EXCEL", True) = 0 Then
    p.Kill()
End If
```

Alternatively if the list is bigger you can use a different aproach.

```
Dim procsToKill() As String = {"WINWORD", "EXCEL", "NOTEPAD"} ' Add more tho this list
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If procsToKill.Contains(p.ProcessName) Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I was looking for another way.. and you provided it.